# Extract specific piece of url-encoded querystring in an <object>/<embed> tag

Tags: php, tags, soundcloud

I want to remove everything, and only want a particular value between tags in php, 
here is the code what I want:

```
<object height="81" width="100%">
    <param name="movie" value="http://player.soundcloud.com/player.swf?url=http%3A%2F%2Fapi.soundcloud.com%2Ftracks%2F17181143"></param> <param name="allowscriptaccess" value="always"></param>
    <embed allowscriptaccess="always" height="81" src="http://player.soundcloud.com/player.swf?url=http%3A%2F%2Fapi.soundcloud.com%2Ftracks%2F17181143" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" width="100%"></embed>
</object>
<span>
    <a href="http://soundcloud.com/kiwinest/linkin-park-iridescent">Linkin Park - Iridescent</a> by <a href="http://soundcloud.com/kiwinest">KiwiNest</a>
</span>
```

I just only want **17181143** this value and want to remove everything else..

Comment: What does `b/w` *mean*, in this context?

Comment: @David: It's shorthand for `between`.. I had to look it up, as I've never seen it used before.

Comment: @jnpcl: my sincere thanks, I spent two minutes trying to look for an `img` tag, to be turned into monochrome. I should probably use Google myself, instead of just asking other people... =)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the [Simple HTML DOM](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net) Library:

```
<?php
    include('lib/simple_html_dom.php');

    $string = '<object height="81" width="100%"> <param name="movie" value="http://player.soundcloud.com/player.swf?url=http%3A%2F%2Fapi.soundcloud.com%2Ftracks%2F17181143"></param> <param name="allowscriptaccess" value="always"></param> <embed allowscriptaccess="always" height="81" src="http://player.soundcloud.com/player.swf?url=http%3A%2F%2Fapi.soundcloud.com%2Ftracks%2F17181143" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" width="100%"></embed> </object>  <span><a href="http://soundcloud.com/kiwinest/linkin-park-iridescent">Linkin Park - Iridescent</a> by <a href="http://soundcloud.com/kiwinest">KiwiNest</a></span>';

    $html = str_get_html($string);
    //$html = file_get_html('http://www.mysite.com/');

    if ($html) {
        foreach ($html->find('object') as $obj) {
            foreach ($obj->find('param') as $par) {
                if ($par->name == 'movie') {
                    $embed = parse_url($par->value);
                    parse_str(urldecode($embed['query']), $val);
                    if (array_key_exists('url', $val)) {
                        $url = parse_url($val['url']);
                        $path = explode('/', $url['path']);
                        $code = array_pop($path);
                        if (is_numeric($code)) {
                            echo 'CODE: ' . $code . PHP_EOL;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
?>
```

**Output:**

```
CODE: 17181143
```

**Notes:**

- Requires external library (DOMDocument doesn't like that fragment)
- Works with multiple embeds (should, anyways.. only tested with sample embed)
- Uses PHP's URL parser (rather than RegEx)

Comment: Thanks so much with phpDOM and your codes it's working great..!!

Answer (score 0):

You can use PHP and REGEX to pull out the numbers into an array and thereby discarding everything else.

```
$my_string = '<object height="81" width="100%"> <param name="movie" 
value="http://player.soundcloud.com/player.swf?url=http%3A%2F 
%2Fapi.soundcloud.com%2Ftracks%2F17181143"></param> 
<param name="allowscriptaccess" value="always"></param> <embed allowscriptaccess="always" 
height="81" src="http://player.soundcloud.com/player.swf?url=http%3A%2F  
%2Fapi.soundcloud.com%2Ftracks%2F17181143" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" width="100%">
</embed> </object>  <span><a href="http://soundcloud.com/kiwinest/linkin-park-iridescent">Linkin 
Park - Iridescent</a> by <a href="http://soundcloud.com/kiwinest">KiwiNest</a></span>';

// Assuming all the numbers are going to be 8 characters long, if they are not, then just change
// the regex.
// look for all numbers that are 8 characters long.
preg_match_all('/[0-9]{8}/', $my_string, $ids);
```

Comment: Thanks but your code give error

**preg_match_all() expects at least 3 parameters**

I just replace **$ids** 
with
`$ids = preg_match_all('/[0-9]{8}/','', $my_string);`

and it only give output 1 
on echo but not those numbers

Comment: @user809307 Sorry about that, I fixed it. See the above code again. It'll be stored in $ids as an array. If you don't know how to access that, then you need to brush up on your PHP.

Comment: But, from the array of numbers, how would s/he determine *which* array-key contains the value s/he needs?

Comment: @David Thomas If you notice, it's the same ID's for both. N/N. So this individual is just seeking to find the ID of this flash embed video. It would simply be $ids[0] (any of the keys will all have the same values, this N) A large part of it is I've worked with these embed flash embed code before. Dunno what s/he's going to do with it, but there you have it.